# Not sure what display to use for this layout

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a layout that I want to flex but the important aspect is that its keeps this consistent spacing between each div / image.  I started to use bootstrap but I thought maybe it needed to be more custom.  I realized you cannot use display:table with display:flex.

Expert css ppl what do you recommend?[image]

Comment: Try CSS Grid Layout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 1):

### Using CSS Grid

The best way to do this is with css grid using [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) & [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
}

.grid>div {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.six {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.seven {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.eight {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
  <div class="seven">Seven</div>
  <div class="eight">Eight</div>
</div>
```

---

### Using Flexbox

Alternatively, to support IE11 it is possible with flexbox, but with a bit more markup.

Ber sure to have a read of the Known Issues section at [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for some *gotchas* before you head down this path.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: #666;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.cellinner {
  margin: 4px;
  min-height: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.cell1,
.cell2 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.cell3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cell3-1 {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.cell4,
.cell5 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.cell6 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cell cell1">
    <div class="cellinner">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
    <div class="cellinner">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell3">
    <div class="cell cell3-1">
      <div class="cellinner">3.1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell3-2">
      <div class="cellinner">3.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell3-3">
      <div class="cellinner">3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell4">
    <div class="cellinner">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell5">
    <div class="cellinner">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell6">
    <div class="cellinner">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The grids are awesome but I have to support lower level version of ie.  IE 11.

Comment: I started using flexbox. Its cool but its obvious I'll definitely need a lot media queries.  Retaking a class in flexbox because there are things I am still confused by.  I want to change the layout on ipad and then on mobile.  I want it be responsive and its KIND of but it definitely needs tweeking.

Comment: Tip: You should start from your mobile view and work your way up, changing for tablet and desktop views only what is necessary.

Comment: media queries should be for tablet and desktop??

Comment: Yes. Do your layout for mobile first, then make small changes with a media query for your tablet breakpoint. Let me know if I can help with anything else.